# trying to get the output of a form to display on same line as <p> element html

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I'm trying to get certain elements of this form to be displayed on the same line: I want the output of the form to be displayed on the same line as "Total: $ " - (I still want the price per lb ($1.00 in this example) to be displayed on the line above and the number spinner to be displayed to the right). I tried to wrap the whole thing in a `<span>` that I set the CSS of to be `display:inline` but it didn't work (& I've tried a few other things as well which also didn't work).
Here's a selection of my code:
HTML:

```
 <div class="caption">
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="amount.value = (quantity.valueAsNumber * (1))">
<legend>$1.00</legend>
<span class="quant"><p><label for="quant">QTY</label>
 <input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="quantity" name="quantity"></p></span>
<span class="inline"><p>Total:$<output name="amount" for="quantity"></output></p></span>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
legend { float: left;
         margin-top: 35px;
         padding-top: 20px;
         margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.inline { display: inline; }
.quant { text-align: right;
            max-width: 30em;
            float: right;
            margin-top: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
legend { float: left;
        
}
.inline { display: inline; }
.quant { text-align: right;
            max-width: 30em;
            float: right;
          
}
form > * { border:1px solid red; line-height:2em }
```

```html
<div class="caption">
    <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="amount.value = (quantity.valueAsNumber * (1))">
        <legend>$1.00</legend>
        <span class="quant">
           
                <label for="quant">QTY</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="quantity" name="quantity">
           
        </span>
        <span>Total:$<output name="amount" for="quantity"></output></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Get rid of your `p` tags. Try not to use dispensable containers and classes. Your code would be more readable. You can change the `line-height` value of `form > *`

Comment: Thanks, @Pcodea Xonos (I'm more a JS person, just trying to get my html up to snuff & need 2 make this from a mock-up)- getting rid of the <p> tags did the trick of getting the "Total" on the same line as the total #. I haven't styled the form yet- is line height the part that aligns it on the same line as number ticker & "QTY" (just to know for future reference as well)? Thanks for your help!